# Why does my code stuck in eclipse at readLine()?

Tags: java

I'm creating a simulation of an NFA and i'm supposed to read from a standard input. I have full working code(Works fine while called from Windows PowerShell script) which doesn't run in Eclipse IDE becuse it stops at second line where is suppsoed to read a line from a stdin. I have stored input in Program arguments and run the program with it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = reader.readLine();  //HERE CODE STOPS
    String InputStrings[] = s.split("\\|");
    int NumberOfInputStrings = InputStrings.length;
    ...
```

I'd like to know what's happening behind this and why this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, did you try **typing something** in the Eclipse Console View and press enter? Did you configure the Run Configuration to "Allocate Control (necessary for input)" on the "Common" tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter the value in the console to read it. It is stopped because it is waiting for your input to provide and read it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i've stored my input in program arguments, doesn't it read it from there?

Comment: If you  are passing as a program arguments then why are you trying to read the BufferReader  ?

Comment: @L.A. No, program arguments are passed to your program in the `args` array of the `main` method, exactly the same way they are passed when giving them on the command-line with running program Windows PowerShell script.

Comment: How does the program work when it it called from PS script and not when it runs in eclipse if the arguments are passed the sam way?

Comment: can you please post how you are invoking this program from PS scripts ?

Comment: param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$testDirectory, //input files
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$outputFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$cleanUp
)
....
Get-Content $testDirectory\test$str\test.a | java -cp bin SimEnka > $outputFile

This is part from the script

Comment: @L.A. In that script, you're piping in the output of another command to the *standard input* of the Java program. You can't change *standard input* when running from Eclipse. Eclipse will by default allow entering input on the Console View, same as Java command will allow entering input from terminal window if you don't pipe anything to the program.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to provide the input so the reader can read it. Run the code and in the Eclipse console type something and press Enter.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i've stored my input in program arguments, doesn't it read it from there?